# let user get direction to specific location from his location in my website

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I tried to combine this links with each other 
"https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation" 
and
"https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel"
but there is a problem with combining together by pushing user current location to a inner html of "div" and then get it back to push it into start of direction path

```js
  <script>
      var  infoWindow;
    function initMap() {
      var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 18,
        center: { lat: 30.0879217, lng: 31.3439407 }
      });
     

      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            document.getElementById("position1").innerHTML=position.coords.latitude;
            document.getElementById("position2").innerHTML=position.coords.longitude;
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
           
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
            infoWindow.open(map);
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        }
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        document.getElementById('mode').addEventListener('change', function () {
            calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
          });

    }
    function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
      var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
      var x=document.getElementById("position1").innerHTML;
      var y=document.getElementById("position2").innerHTML;
    
      directionsService.route({
        origin: { lat: 30.0879217, lng: 31.3439407 },  // Haight.
        destination: { lat: Number(x), lng: Number(y) },  // Ocean Beach.
        // Note that Javascript allows us to access the constant
        // using square brackets and a string value as its
        // "property."
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
      }, function (response, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCb0QRzb5LcbAkUbRH3kRDv4WNVDRMBeq4&callback=initMap">
  </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Travel modes in directions</title>
  <style>
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }

    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #floating-panel {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      left: 25%;
      z-index: 5;
      background-color: #fff;
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #999;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
      line-height: 30px;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="position1" ></div> 
    <div id="position2"></div> 
  
  <div id="floating-panel">
    <b>Mode of Travel: </b>
    <select id="mode">
      <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
      <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
      <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
      <option value="TRANSIT">Transit</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: The geolocation function is asynchronous. You need to use the results in the callback function when/where it is available (storing them away happens to late, the results aren't available for the call to the directions service).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<script>
    var  infoWindow;
    function initMap() {
        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            document.getElementById("position1").innerHTML=position.coords.latitude;
            document.getElementById("position2").innerHTML=position.coords.longitude;
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };

            var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 18,
                center: { lat: 30.0879217, lng: 31.3439407 }
            });

            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
            infoWindow.open(map);
            map.setCenter(pos);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
            document.getElementById('mode').addEventListener('change', function () {
                calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
            });
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        }


    }
    function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
      var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
      var x=document.getElementById("position1").innerHTML;
      var y=document.getElementById("position2").innerHTML;

      directionsService.route({
        origin: { lat: 30.0879217, lng: 31.3439407 },  // Haight.
        destination: { lat: Number(x), lng: Number(y) },  // Ocean Beach.
        // Note that Javascript allows us to access the constant
        // using square brackets and a string value as its
        // "property."
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
      }, function (response, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCb0QRzb5LcbAkUbRH3kRDv4WNVDRMBeq4&callback=initMap">
  </script>
```

Your code crash because you tried to read your position in the `calculateAndDisplayRoute` before the browser calls your callback where you initialize the lat and long HTML's objects.

*Tell me if you have some questions or comments.*

Comment: Big Thanks for helping me

Comment: Problem appear now that the map hide when i include jquery library <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>@S.P.H.I.N.X